# Tracking user's bandwidth

Tags: php, linux, apache, tracking, bandwidth

I'm building a site where users can have their own free sites.  They can upload pictures, add content, customize themes / designs and etc... all free.  I want to limit each users panel / site to 1GB monthly bandwidth or at least track it.

Each users site would be wwww.myfreesites(ie).com/[username]/

The web site runs on linux (if that helps).

Ideally, I'd like PHP to track each users bandwidth usage and lock the account (via mysql query) when 1GB is limited on the month / day is back to the beginning.

Thanks!`

Comment: Did you hear about GeoCities ?   :-)

Comment: I'm using the "GeoCities" as an example; I'm not going to disclose my actual project :)

Answer (score 0):

Build an interface in PHP through which they upload content. This way you can see how much content they uploaded. Getting the bandwith consumed by traffic though can be trickier.

I'd suggest using the server generated logs and build a script that parses the data to calculate the amount of traffic and size of the downloaded objects. I'm not sure which log would give you that but if you contact the hosting company (suppose you'd use a dedicated server) they can surely tell you.

Comment: Well tracking how much they upload doesn't bother me.  It's the # of viewers they have that will absorb the bandwidth that does.

Comment: It sounds as if I may need to create a cron job to parse apache logs

Comment: Sure, as long as you can get the right logs and parsing. Possibly scheduled cron jobs so you don't kill the server. Running the script daily for each user should do the trick.